# ActivityCompat.requestPermissions not working

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

Calling ActivityCompat.requestPermissions does not display the UI dialog box.

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{"Manifest.permission.READ_SMS"}, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
```

However, if I change the minSDKversion to 23 and run

```
requestPermissions(new String[]{"android.permission.READ_SMS"}, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
```

the dialog appears. Why? BTW. to run it on the emulator requires that the emulator will be targeting API 23.

Comment: REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS can't be too big, try to make it ``100``.

Comment: @saisam what?  That makes no sense and is not mentioned anywhere in the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html

Comment: Please set targetsdk in gradle to 23 inorder to show runtime permissions

Answer (score 8):

> Why?

Probably because you have the wrong permission name in the first code snippet. Either use:

```
Manifest.permission.READ_SMS
```

or use:

```
"android.permission.READ_SMS"
```

**Do not use:**

```
"Manifest.permission.READ_SMS"
```

Comment: Tried that already - giving me "cannot resolve symbol READ_SMS". That is why I tried the string version as posted above.

Comment: @Zvi: "giving me "cannot resolve symbol READ_SMS"" -- did you add the `import` for `android.Manifest`? `android.Manifest.permission.READ_SMS` has been around [since API Level 1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_SMS). And, if you read [the documentation for `READ_SMS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_SMS), you will see that the string value of the `android.Manifest.permission.READ_SMS` constant is `"android.permission.READ_SMS"`.

Comment: You were right, I did not have that import. I am so used to the fact that Android Studio is prompting for the imports that I failed to check if it imported all the libraries needed in that activity. Maybe it is a bug in AS because it did not prompt for the import of that library, and when I googled for READ_SMS I did not find any solution talking about the import. Thx.

Comment: I have this problem today, and I use the Manifest.permission.X, have the right stuff in AndroidManifest.xml. I call `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS}, 1);` but nothing appears on-screen...

Comment: @Ted: For that one, you need to have `targetSdk` set for Android 13, see https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission#declare

Comment: Thanks, I do have that actually:     defaultConfig {
        applicationId "test.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 29
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 60
        versionName "1.60"
    }

I was consideriong if running this in onCreate was the problem, but doesnt seem to be. Maybe another So question is warranted =)

Comment: So, here goes =) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74694632/android-activitycompat-requestpermissions-does-not-show-a-popup-android-13-ta

Answer (score 2):

New versions of Android Studio adds the AppCompat library and Android Design Support library dependencies automatically in your build.gradle file on new project creation. If not add the following two lines to the dependencies section of the app’s build.gradle file.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have already added the requested permission in Android's manifest file like before Android M, only then you will get expected behaviour.

Add the permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
```

Comment: An answer was already given by @CommonWare - see my comment as of Sep 21, 2015