# Android: ActivityCompat.requestPermissions does not show a popup (Android 13, targetSdkVersion=33)

Tags: android, notifications, android-permissions

There are many ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32671245/activitycompat-requestpermissions-not-working/), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45933131/activitycompat-requestpermissions-doesnt-show-dialog-in-android), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37140519/activitycompat-requestpermissions-does-not-show-prompt), [four](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69012395/activitycompat-requestpermissions-does-not-show-dialog-for-access-fine-location)) questions on this topic on SO already. However, none of the answers I have found so far resolves the issue for me.

The problem is that the `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions` does not trigger a popup, asking the user to give permission for notifications.

Setup:

- Testing on physical device (Android 13, Pixel 6)
- Targeting SDK version 33 (targetSdkVersion=33)
- minSdkVersion = 29
- AndroidManifest has permission: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATION" />`
- in onCreate in an otherwise working Activity, I do:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
{
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS}, 1);
}
```

and the callback is  like so:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(MainScreenActivity.this, "Woho, you have enabled notifications!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainScreenActivity.this, "Ouch, this is gonna hurt without notifications", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
    }
}
```

Here are the build.gradle files:

`TheApp\build.gradle`

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://raw.github.com/xujiaao/mvn-repository/master/releases' }
        maven {
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
        }
        maven { url 'http://dl.bintray.com/ahmedrizwan/maven'
            allowInsecureProtocol = true
        }
        google()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'  // Google Services plugin
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.5.2'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:10.0.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local'
            allowInsecureProtocol = true
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'src/main/libs'
        }
    }
}
```

`TheApp\app\build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    buildFeatures{
        dataBinding = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "test.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 29
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 60
        versionName "1.60"

    }
    buildTypes {

        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug_keystore
            aaptOptions.setProperty("cruncherEnabled", false)
        }

        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release_keystore
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            aaptOptions.setProperty("cruncherEnabled", false)
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    namespace 'test.myapp'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.3.0'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update:2.0.1'

    def fragment_version = "1.5.4"

    // Java language implementation
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:$fragment_version"
    // Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragment_version"
    // Testing Fragments in Isolation
    debugImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:$fragment_version"
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Play services Gradle plugin
```

I have stepped through the code via the debugger, and can confirm that the `requestPermissions` is executed, but that the `onRequestPermissionsResult` is triggered immediately with no popup on device.

I also [read this](https://forums.malwarebytes.com/topic/290668-android-13-blocking-notifications/), but I figured that it was down to developers not implementing the opt-in model as described [here](https://source.android.com/docs/core/display/notification-perm), but maybe, this is an issue after all? Because I cannot make sense of this...

### Update

I ask for other permissions in other parts of the app, and this line works well - I get the popup to grant permission:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, BaseActivity.PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION_CODE);
```

### Update 2

In another part of the code base, I have the same requestPermission call, but for another permission, and this works fine:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, BaseActivity.PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION_CODE);
}
```

When this is executed, I get this:

[image]

But, if I change the requestPermissions call so it looks like this, nothing happens and I get to the callback immediately, with a "rejected":

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS}, BaseActivity.PHONE_STATE_PERMISSION_CODE);
}
```

Picture:

[image]

### Update 3

I have also tried using the new `ActivityResultLauncher`, but the behaviour is the same - it goes directly to the callback without showing any popup.

Comment: current support/compat/androidx libs?

Comment: Updated question with build.gradles

Comment: Yes for POST_NOTIFICATIONS there is no permission dialog. Its just granted. Like many others. Try READ_MEDIA_IMAGES instead for a pop up.

Comment: @blackapps that is not what the docs say...

Comment: @blackapps - now you need some coffee or break.. :) [`POST_NOTIFICATIONS`](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission#user-choice) do show dialog and [`READ_MEDIA_IMAGES`](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/behavior-changes-13#granular-media-permissions) is just a newer `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` only for images, there is no word for accessing filesystem by OP...

Comment: I'm about to call it a day ;-)

Comment: Instead of ***onRequestPermissionsResult*** which is now deprecated, I believe we should use ***ActivityResultLauncher***. https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#request-permission https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66551781/android-onrequestpermissionsresult-is-deprecated-are-there-any-alternatives

Comment: I looked at that one, but it was optional as far as I understood it? And the other version see med much easier to implement (found no examples of the other version,rhe PermissionRequest i think it was called)...

Comment: I tried using the code on the SO link you posted, but there is no change, the same behaviour as when using the code in my question above. Interesting thing: after `onActivityResult` is called (the callback in `ActivityResultLauncher`), then also the `onRequestPermissionsResult` is called.

Comment: What an odd problem with the Android 13 SDK. Let's say we change **minSdkVersion** to 33 to see what happens. Alternatively, if it does go into the **onRequestPermissionsResult** method/callback, try logging the output of ***result.get(Manifest.permission.POST NOTIFICATIONS)***.

Comment: On the other hand, `grantResults[0]` in your code only checks the first entry... If you pass a lot of permissions, this could be a problem. However, because it is only passing one permission, this is not an issue.

Comment: Hey @ecle, thankks for input. 1)  I will try to change minSdkVersion. 2) Logg hte output of... What do you mean? 3) grantResults aint the problem, it is -1 in there, the problem is that I never get a popup for this one...

Comment: Java: `ActivityResultLauncher<String[]> permissionRequest = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions(), result ->{ Log.i("PERMISSIONS", String.format("POST_NOTIFICATIONS=%s", result.get(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)));}); permissionRequest.launch(new String[]{Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS});`

Comment: To test, refer https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission#test

Comment: I added some updates above, which makes this even more mysterious.

Comment: Examine this demo, which does not use the ***ActivityCompat.requestPermissions*** call as it needs the deprecated ***AppCompatActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult*** call but rather the most recent **ActivityResultLauncher** approach. https://www.droidcon.com/2022/03/21/notification-runtime-permission-android13/

Comment: It is because you have already rejected the permission a few times already or you have deliberately disabled it in the app settings. Try to clear app data or uninstall and re-install the app.

Comment: Thanks, but: @ecle I have also tried using the ActivityResultLauncher, exact same results - goes directly to the result callback, no popup is ever seen.

Comment: @SovathnaHong I have uninstalled and reinstalled the app like 100 times by now. Every time I reinstall and start, I get the "make and manage phone calls" permission popup, so I know for sure that the app is considered "new" and that permission is not set, thus the popup is displayed. However, the POST_NOTIFICATIONS does not show.

Comment: @Ted have you tested it according to the guide? https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission#test

Comment: @ecle No, but the issue is resolved, see below. A typo! =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stupid me. In the Q above, I did post what the AndroidManifest contained, and I wrote:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATION" />`

This is not correct. I am missing an `s`, it shoul be:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />`

Oops! :-)

Comment: Glad in your case you found that you missed S, letter. In my case I have S included, i.e., <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>

My app is built over ReactNative, I add the permission in AndroidManifest, requesting the permission which is not showing me the popup. Am using Android 13 Emulator with google playstore.

Comment: Which approach do use req permission?=

Comment: I made even stupider mistake: forgot to declare this permission in the manifest entirely. 30 min of wasted time. This would be a perfect place for Android to throw an exception to spare us all this trouble.